# Show that the Poisson distribution is a valid probability statement.

Tags: probability

Fix a real number $\lambda >0$ and set $\Omega=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$. To each $i\in\Omega$ assign the probability  $$p_i=\dfrac{\lambda^i}{i!} e^{-\lambda}.$$

Verify that this a valid probability assignment.

I know that if I sum $p_i$ from $0$ to $\infty$ it must be 1. Is there anything else i must check for?

Comment: That $0\leq p_i\leq 1$.

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: it is enough to check $p_i\geq0$ and $\sum_ip_i=1$. If this is true then *automatically* $p_j\leq\sum_ip_i=1$ for each $j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0 \leq p_i \leq 1$ is clear.

We know that $e^{\lambda} = \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}$ (serie expansion).

Then $\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}e^{-\lambda} = 1$

Comment: $p_i\leq1$ might not be clear for the OP. Fortunately that part of the check is redundant, since it is implied by $p_i\leq\sum_jp_j=1$